# React Native - send data from native to javascript/bridging

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm very new to React Native (iOS) and I have read a lot about Bridging, however I cannot seem to make this working.

I need to be able to send an object/string from AppDelegate to JavaScript. My AppDelegate returns a UserName which is retrieved by a native code in one of my methods inside AppDelegate.

I tried to use in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
```

and then

```
@synthesize bridge = _bridge;
```

and inside my method

```
  NSString *eventName = notification.userInfo[@"name"];
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"EventReminder"
                                               body:@{@"name": eventName}];
```

but none of the above works and I'm getting errors. Do I need to do anything to `AppDelegate.h` as well?

Can anyone please help me? What is the easiest way to sent data from native to javascript?

**UPDATE:**

I found a workaround, but I don't think it's effective as I'm calling `RCTRootView` twice. First to load the app with `initialProperties` nil, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;


 jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];



  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"myApp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];



  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [self getUsername];

}
```

And for the second time when I retrieve a UserName I then update `initialProperties` like this:

```
-(void) getUsername {

    //3rd party code to retrieve the username

            NSString *username = username

      NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

      jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

      RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:nil];

      RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                       moduleName:@"myApp"
                                                initialProperties: @{@"username" : username}];



      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
      UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
      rootViewController.view = rootView;
      self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


}
```

By doing the way above I'm then able to send and receive username via `this.props` in JavaScript.

But like I said, I'm not sure this is an effective way as I'm calling `RCTRootView` twice.

Any help is appreciated please.

Comment: When is the method you are creating being called? It might be that it is getting called too early and the RN portion of the app has not been initialized?

Comment: @rmevans9 I have updated my question

Comment: Couldn't you make the getUsername call simply call out to the third party and export getUsername to JavaScript via the bridge and then just call getUsername? When I'm at a machine I'll link some documentation that talks about how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could, instead of trying to put it in the initial launch code on the iOS side, put it in a Native Module that you export a function to return the information from. See React Natives official documentation on it: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I was actually thinking of doing that, but for what I need  'sending just one object to javascript' I find it unnecessary. Isn't there an easier way to 'bridge' it and not to call 'rootView' twice?